# python TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable in a program for monthly payment

Tags: python

```
    month = 1
while month < 13:
     monthly_interest_rate = annualInterestRate/12.0
     min_monthlypayment = monthlyPaymentRate * balance
     monthlyUnpaidBalance = balance - min_monthlypayment
     updated_balance = monthlyUnpaidBalance + (monthly_interest_rate * monthlyUnpaidBalance)
     print "Month: " + str(month)
     print "Minimum monthly payment : " + str(round(min_monthlypayment, 2))
     print "Remaining balance: " + str(round(updated_balance, 2))
     balance = updated_balance
     month = month + 1
print "Total paid : " + round(sum(min_monthlypayment), 2)
print "Remaining balance: " + round(updated_balance, 2)
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error if not using any iteration.

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: sum(min_monthlypayment): sum is waiting for an iterable(list for example) not a float...

Comment: So how I can make a sum of the monthly payments without this error?

Comment: Keep a seperate variable where you add your min_monthlypayment every time you loop and just print that when you print the total paid.

Alternatively, if you need to keep track of how much is paid every month you can append each month's payment to a list, and then use sum() on the list of monthly payment amounts like you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating when you are trying to take the sum. My suggestion would be to keep your code and store the variable in an array and then take the sum at the end so:

```
    import numpy as np
    sum_arr = np.zeros(12)
    a = 0
    under min_monthlypayment put: sum_arr[a] = min_monthlypayment
    under month = month + 1 put: a = a+1
    then to get the sum use np.sum(sum_arr)
```